# Azure Synapse, Data Duplication Issue in PySpark When Reading and Writing to Delta Lake

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I'm working on a PySpark data pipeline that reads Salesforce User data from an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 "bronze" layer, transforms the data, and then writes it to a "silver" layer in Delta Lake. The problem I'm facing is that, despite using the dropDuplicates(["Id"]) function in PySpark to remove any duplicate records based on the "Id" column, I'm still encountering duplicate "Id" records in my "silver" layer. This duplication issue persists even after repeated runs of the pipeline, and it's causing significant problems in downstream analyses and processes that rely on this data.

To handle the potential issue of duplicate records, I included the dropDuplicates(["Id"]) function in my PySpark script. This function is used after the union operation, which combines the existing "silver" data with the new "bronze" data. My expectation was that this function would ensure that any duplicate records (based on the "Id" column) would be removed from the combined dataset before it is written back to the "silver" layer in Delta Lake.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
# Combine the bronze and silver data and deduplicate based on the "Id" column
deduplicated_df = bronze_df.union(silver_df).dropDuplicates(["Id"])

# Write the deduplicated data to the silver layer
deduplicated_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(prod_user_silver_path)
```

Sample data after running pipelines 3x:

[image]

The result I was expecting was a "silver" layer dataset with no duplicate "Id" records. However, what I'm actually seeing is duplicate "Id" entries in the "silver" layer despite using dropDuplicates(["Id"]). This discrepancy between my expected and actual outcomes is the core issue I'm trying to resolve.

Any thoughts?

Comment: please provide sample input data of bronze and silver layer.

Comment: is there any partition on any column? try  this `bronze_df.union(silver_df).repartition("Id").dropDuplicates(["Id"])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jayashankarGS

Thank you for your response and the suggestions you provided. I appreciate your help. While I did get the correct output in the dataframe after following your suggestions, I still encountered duplicates when using the data in PowerBi. However, I was able to find a solution to this issue recently.

To resolve the problem, I modified my approach by writing the data from the Delta back to a single Parquet file, overwriting any existing data. I then stored this Parquet file in my "gold" layer. This additional step ensured that the duplicates were eliminated, and the data in my "gold" layer was clean and free of any duplicate "Id" records.

Thank you once again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your code in my environment, it worked successfully.

[image]

After dropping duplicates.

[image]

For you it still getting duplicates in end table, below are the possible causes.

1. **Data type** mismatch.

Print schema of both dataframe.

```
bronze_df.printSchema()
silver_df.printSchema()
```

If there is mismatch between these columns datatype use below code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

bronze_df = bronze_df.withColumn("Id", col("Id").cast("string"))
silver_df = silver_df.withColumn("Id", col("Id").cast("string"))

deduplicated_df = bronze_df.union(silver_df).dropDuplicates(["Id"])
```

2.**Data partitioning**
Duplicate records might exist in single partition even though you deduplicate overall dataset.

you can use below code for above issue.

```
deduplicated_df = bronze_df.union(silver_df).repartition("Id").dropDuplicates(["Id"])
```

3. **Spaces** in the data.

[image]

code:

```
sp_df.withColumn("Id",trim(col("Id"))).dropDuplicates(["Id"]).show()
```

[image]

If you still not getting expected results by following above ways.
Try this.

```
bronze_df.union(silver_df).groupBy(col("Id")).agg(first(col("name")))
```

[image]